# How can I add a "Buy It Now" price to an existing auction item?

Tags: ebay

I created an auction item on eBay yesterday, and today I've had a user ask if they can "Buy It Now" as they require the item ASAP.

I went to edit/revise the item, and the Buy It Now field was disabled from editing.

Is there a way of editing the Buy It Now field on an existing item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't attach a "buy it now" after the auction is live, its currently in play.

See here: http://pages.ebay.com/help/sell/fixed-price.html#changing

> Changing your listing format
>
> You can't switch between a fixed price listing and an online auction
>   with a Buy It Now price. However, in some situations, you can add,
>   edit, or remove a Buy It Now price.
>
> - For auction-style listings: If more than 12 hours remain before the listing ends, you might be able to add, edit, or remove a Buy It
>     Now price **as long as the listing has not received any bids**.
> - For fixed price listings: You can edit the Buy It Now price.

Answer (score 2):

Ok !

Look at http://pages.ebay.com/help/sell/fixed-price.html !

> **Changing your listing format**
>
> You can't switch between a fixed price listing and an online auction
>   with a Buy It Now price. However, in some situations, you can add,
>   edit, or remove a Buy It Now price.
>
> - **For auction-style listings:** If more than 12 hours remain before the listing ends, you might be able to add, edit, or remove a Buy It
>     Now price as long as the listing has not received any bids.
> - **For fixed price listings:** You can edit the Buy It Now price.

Comment: Thanks @bZezzz! It states that items cant have a Buy It Now price added to an item which already has bids. Mine has 2 bids. What can I do?